# 11*(...) as a bash parameter without quotation marks

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a small piece of code that passes a small formula to another program, however i've found that something strange happens when the formula starts with 11*(:

```
$ echo 11*15
```

Neatly prints '11*15'

```
$ echo 21*(15)
```

Neatly prints '21*(15)', while

```
echo 11*(15)
```

Only gives '11'. As far as I've found this only happens with '11*('. I know that this can be solved by using proper quotation marks, but I'm still curious as to why this happens.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Do you have a file called 11?

Comment: A file called `11` wouldn't explain the behavior -- and in fact I can't think of anything that would.  I get `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`.

Comment: Try the following: `touch 1115; echo 11*(15)`. On my bash, that returns `1115` since `11*(15)` matches a filename in the current directory.

Comment: @darvids0n: Really? The same command gives me a syntax error (see above), with both bash 3.2.48 and 4.2.8.  Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: @Keith: Yup. Xubuntu 11.04, bash `4.2.8(1)` latest from repos (`4.2-0ubuntu3`).

Comment: Here's an Ubuntu-specific change for 4.2, could *maybe* affect behaviour in this case but it's unlikely: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/728748

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your program coded? If its coded to take in parameters, then pass your formula like

```
./myprogram "11*15"
```

or

```
echo '11*15' | myprogram
```

If you do echo just like that on the command line, you may inadvertently display files that has `11` in its file name

Comment: +1 You should definitely put quotation marks around it, why would you choose not to? The idea of quoting a string as a shell parameter is to avoid things like this where it will accidentally trigger something else in the shell and not echo the same exact string back. Bash shell docs state: *Quoting is used to remove the special meaning of certain characters or words to the shell.  Quoting can be used to disable special treatment for special characters, to prevent reserved words from being recognized as such, and to prevent parameter expansion.*

Comment: I hadn't thought of checking whether there was a file name in the home directory starting with 11 yet. I checked and there was a file named only 11. After removing it echo works normally. Of course quotation marks would have worked, but my curiosity is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

`11*(15)` uses a Bash-specific extended glob syntax.  You've stumbled across it accidentally, emphasizing why quotation marks are a good idea.  (I also learned a lot tracking down why it was working differently for me; thanks for that.)

The behavior of

```
echo 11*(15)
```

in bash is going to vary depending on whether `extglob` is enabled.  If it's enabled `*(PATTERN-LIST)` matches zero or more occurrences of the patterns.  If it's disabled, it doesn't, and the resulting `(` is likely to cause a syntax error.

For example:

```
$ ls
11  115  1155  11555  115555
$ shopt -u extglob
$ echo 11*(55)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo 11*(55)
11 1155 115555
$
```

(This explains the odd behavior I discussed in comments.)

Quoting from the bash 4.2.8 documentation (`info bash`):

> If the `extglob' shell option is enabled using the `shopt' builtin,
>   several extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In the
>   following description, a PATTERN-LIST is a list of one or more
>   patterns separated by a `|'.  Composite patterns may be formed using
>   one or more of the following sub-patterns:
>
> `?(PATTERN-LIST)'
>        Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns.
>
> `*(PATTERN-LIST)'
>        Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns.
>
> `+(PATTERN-LIST)'
>        Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.
>
> `@(PATTERN-LIST)'
>        Matches one of the given patterns.
>
> `!(PATTERN-LIST)'
>        Matches anything except one of the given patterns.